# Implement a doubly linked list in C

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I want to insert a node at the beginning of linked list, whenever `insertAtBeginning` method is called. My code builds well, but i don't get the desired output.

I get the following output:

```
0------>NULL
```

The desired output is:

```
9------>8------>7------>6------>5------>4------>3------>2------>1------>0------>NULL
```

Following is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct dll{
    int data;
    struct dll* previous;
    struct dll* next;
};


struct dll* insertAtBeginning(int a, struct dll* head){

    if(head == NULL){
        head->data = a;
        head->previous = NULL;
        head->next = NULL;
        return head;
    }
    else{
        struct dll *first;
        first = (struct dll*) malloc( sizeof(struct dll));
        first->data = a;
        first->next = head;
        head->previous = first;
        first->previous = NULL;
        head = first;
        free(first);
        return head;
    }
}


void display_from_first(struct dll* head){
    struct dll *temp;
    temp = head;

    printf("\nThe linked list contains: ");
    while(temp != NULL) {
        printf("%d------>",temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("NULL\n");
    free(temp);
    }


int main(){
    int i = 0;
    struct dll *head1, *tail1;
    head1 = (struct dll*) malloc( sizeof(struct dll));
    head1->next = NULL;
    head1->previous = NULL;

    for(i=0; i<10; i++){
        insertAtBeginning(i, head1);
    }

    display_from_first(head1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why on earth is your insert code doing `head = first;
        free(first);` — your code will crash.   What output do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are mainly two problems here :

1. `free(first)` : This is not required as you wish to save the memory you just allocated, not delete it.
2. Your `insertAtBeginning()` function returns a pointer to `head`, so in `main()`, where you are calling this function change it to `head1=insertAtBeginning(i, head1);` This way your head is also saved.

Here's the code with the two edits :

http://ideone.com/nXwc8z

Comment: After updating the pointer and removing the `free` statement, I get the stackdump error!! It worked good till i freed `first` pointer.

Comment: I ran the same code over codeBlocks... but got Stackdump error

Comment: Let me check on codeblocks then, because it works well on ideone.

Comment: Yeah, it worked...!! I had removed `head1 = (struct dll*) malloc( sizeof(struct dll));
    head1->next = NULL;
    head1->previous = NULL;` statements before running it..

Comment: Glad it helped! I was about to suggest one more thing : when displaying, you need to to change the condition `while(temp!=NULL)` to `(while(temp->next!=NULL), as it printed erroneous data at last output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72968/discussion-between-jainam-jhaveri-and-ayushi-jha).

Answer (score 3):

The code for a doubly linked list is much cleaner if you start with an empty list of two nodes as shown below.

[image]

That way you don't have to deal with special cases like `if(head==NULL)`. There's always a node before and after the node that is being inserted (or deleted), so you just hook things up and you're done.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct s_node Node;
struct s_node
{
    Node *prev;
    Node *next;
    int  data;
};

Node *insertAtBeginning( Node *head, int value )
{
    // allocate memory for the new node
    Node *node = malloc( sizeof(Node) );
    if ( node == NULL )
        return NULL;

    // insert the node at the beginning of the list
    Node *temp = head->next;
    head->next = node;
    temp->prev = node;

    // fill in the fields of the node
    node->prev = head;
    node->next = temp;
    node->data = value;

    return node;
}

void showList( Node *head )
{
    Node *node;

    printf( "The list contains: " );
    for ( node = head->next; node->next != NULL; node = node->next )
        printf( "%d--->", node->data );
    printf( "NULL\n" );
}

int main( void )
{
    // create an empty list with two nodes
    Node head = { NULL , NULL, 0 };
    Node tail = { &head, NULL, 0 };
    head.next = &tail;

    // insert more nodes
    for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
        insertAtBeginning( &head, i );

    // display the list
    showList( &head );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't `free(first);` in `insertAtBeginning()`.

code [here.](http://ideone.com/4xr3gP)

And btw when you have empty list your `display_from_first()` prints `The linked list contains: 0------>NULL` because of

```
head1 = (struct dll*) malloc( sizeof(struct dll));
head1->next = NULL;
head1->previous = NULL;
```

in `main()`. Remove it from main to have correct output

Answer (score 2):

You have several mistakes here.

1) Your function `insertAtBeginning` returns pointer to changed list, but you do not update pointer to head of list in the main function.

2) You are freeing just allocated pointer to new node in the insertion function. You think that you are freeing pointer, but actually you say that this place in memory is not needed more and so your node can't be there.

Comment: After updating the pointer and removing the `free` statement, I get the stackdump error!! It worked good till i freed `first` pointer.